# Sum the values of a csv file based on a match from user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

## Problem Description

I have a csv file that has 3 bits of information as seen below which are separated by commas. I have my code which currently returns me the 2nd and 3rd value as I'd like if I enter the first value exactly as it's written.

Example my input from the user if entered as 25.803.1.1 does tell me name = BALLOON and connections equals 357. I would like to make this work in which the user inputs 25.803.1.1 it will advise connections equals 357, but if the user enters 25.803. it would give the connections sum from everything matching 25.803. If the user entered 25. that it would give the sum of connections for everything starting with 25.

So I assume I need an if statement that could see if there were 1 decimal or 2 decimal places or 3 decimal places and then print out the result. I'm not sure if it would be best to do some sort of grouping, filtering or matching or if I need to create a new list that splits the first bit of date by decimal into a list which would look like [[25], [803], [1], [1]] for an example and then try indexing it based upon what the user inputs somehow. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

## Current Code that works if entered as 25.803.1.1

```
with open("D:/Python/Data/rttData.csv") as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    enbIDs = []
    enbNames = []
    enbRRCs = []

    for row in readCSV:
        enbID = row[0]
        enbName = row[1]
        enbRRC = row[2]

        enbNames.append(enbName)
        enbIDs.append(enbID)
        enbRRCs.append(enbRRC)

siteSelection = input('Enter the eNB number below to search for [ex: 25.803.1.1]')
enbIndex = enbIDs.index(siteSelection)
theName = enbNames[enbIndex]
theRRC = enbRRCs[enbIndex]
print('The name of site', siteSelection, 'is:', theName,'and the RRC Connections are:',theRRC)
```

## CSV File

```
25.803.1.1,BALLOON,357
25.803.2.1,BALLOON,1941
25.803.3.1,BALLOON,3802
25.803.12.2,BALLOON,18783
25.803.22.2,BALLOON,20136
25.803.32.2,BALLOON,17560
25.803.14.4,BALLOON,2661
25.803.24.4,BALLOON,3472
25.803.34.4,BALLOON,4379
25.804.1.1,BANK,8410
25.804.2.1,BANK,7656
25.804.3.1,BANK,9822
25.804.12.2,BANK,9418
25.804.22.2,BANK,20522
25.804.32.2,BANK,14694
25.804.14.4,BANK,17569
25.804.24.4,BANK,16137
25.804.34.4,BANK,13835
```

Comment: `enbIDs.index(siteSelection)` returns the index (if found) of _one_ item, and the exact one. Using list comprehension, and enumerate, and a test, you could generate the list of indexes matching a condition.

Comment: Instead of modifying your question to gain more information, please ask a separate question. Feel free to cross-reference the questions to make them easy to find. **Example:** Add a reference to question B from question A, and add a reference to question A from question B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the ID of each record to see it there is a partial match to your query. The following solution does just that by using the `startswith` string method. A more intelligent partial match could be implemented, but this should get you on the right track.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import collections
import csv
import itertools

Record = collections.namedtuple('Record', 'id, name, rrc')


def main():
    with open('rttData.csv', newline='') as file:
        records = tuple(itertools.starmap(Record, csv.reader(file)))
    query = input('Enter the ID to search for: ')
    for record in filter(lambda item: item.id.startswith(query), records):
        print(f'ID:   {record.id}\nName: {record.name}\nRRC:  {record.rrc}\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hello Noctis, that function worked great. It currently displays all the results. I'd like to know how to make it sum the RRC connections. Example if I enter 25.806 that it will sum all the record.rrc. I've tried various methods of sum to it and nothing works. Any final assistance is greatly appreciated.